# Netgear MBRN3000 3G router gives "Connection Refused" errors

Tags: windows-7, router, iis, 3g

I'm trying to setup my wireless 3G Netgear MBRN3000 router but I cant even access the setup page. I have reset it several times, restarted it, checked the connection, checked its IP with `ipconfig` (192.168.0.2) but no matter what I do I can't visit the setup page in either Internet Explorer or Chrome. All I get is a "Connection Refused" error.

I'm running IIS7 and VMware on the same machine (Windows 7) but I'm not sure if that could be causing my problems. At first I was directed to the IIS default page when accessing 192.160.0.1/2 but when changing its listening IP to 192.168.0.50 all I get is this error message instead. I've tried the routerlogin.net address as well but the browser says it can't be resolved.

What could be causing this? Where do I continue looking for a cause?